# How to check what components are using standard fields uisng Dependency API?

Tags: metadata, tooling-api, dependency-api

This is the process I am following to see what components are dependent on CustomField : `Account.Foo__c`

1. First get Id of custom field:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query="SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM CustomField WHERE DeveloperName = 'Foo' AND TableEnumOrId = 'Account'" --u devsandbox --usetoolingapi
```

Output:

```
ID                  DEVELOPERNAME
──────────────────  ─────────────
00N800000011111EAY  Foo
```

2. Use the above Id and run query against MetadataDependency table.

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT RefMetadataComponentType,RefMetadataComponentName,MetadataComponentName,MetadataComponentType FROM MetadataComponentDependency WHERE RefMetadataComponentId IN ('00N800000011111EAY') " --usetoolingapi --u devsandbox
```

Output:

```
REFMETADATACOMPONENTTYPE  REFMETADATACOMPONENTNAME  METADATACOMPONENTNAME                     METADATACOMPONENTTYPE
────────────────────────  ────────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────────
CustomField               Foo                       SomeClass                                 ApexClass
```

If I want to do the same for standard field `Account.Name`, How can I do that? `CustomField` doesn't have entries for standard fields.

Comment: Not supported by the API at the moment.

Comment: Ya, I think that is the reason we see "where is this used" button only for custom fields.